# mysql too many connection warning

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the following error when running this cron job. It runs every minute:

Error

```
    <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections in <b>/home/eterna33/public_html/script/email_cron.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />


    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in <b>/home/eterna33/public_html/script/email_cron.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in <b>/home/eterna33/public_html/script/email_cron.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in <b>/home/eterna33/public_html/script/email_cron.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
```

Here is the code that runs in the cron job every minute.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","**","****","***");



$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE status=false");
$count="0";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $count++;
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mail SET status=true WHERE id='$row[id]'");
        mail($row['send_to'], $row['subject'], $row['message'], $row['headers']);
        mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM mail WHERE status=true AND id='$row[id]'");
        if ($count >= 3) {
            echo "exit";
            mysqli_close($con);

            exit;
        }
    }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I've contacted the host but they say that they "aren't trained" to debug code. I am at loss for what is wrong. The code functions normally, it just gives these errors.

Comment: The error means that the MySQL server has too many active connections. Either your host needs to raise the number of connections or you need a new host.

Comment: Well then the staff at your hosting company "are incompetent" and I hope you're not "paying too much money" for it. My suggestion would be to put a timer on your code, because it's probably taking longer than a minute to complete and then you're piling up copies of the script until you run out of MySQL connections. Which is the better problem to have instead of running out of memory or CPU resources.

Comment: Make use of persistent connections. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.allow-persistent

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Normally that's a good idea, but if it's a cron job, the process dies, and all connections with it, so that doesn't really help in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be retrieving more information than you need, and then abandoning your partially read result set, each time you run this script. You only handle three items each time through. Abandoned result sets are not great for database servers.

I suggest you change this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE status=false
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE status=false LIMIT 3
```

Then, I suggest you change your loop code as follows:

```
$count = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $count++;
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mail SET status=true WHERE id='$row[id]'");
    mail($row['send_to'], $row['subject'], $row['message'], $row['headers']);
    mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM mail WHERE status=true AND id='$row[id]'");
}

mysqli_close($con);
if ($count > 0) {
   echo "exit";
}
```

It seems that you want the `echo` command used only if the result set was not empty, and this still does that.  But it always reads all the way through each result set.

Also, it doesn't fetch more rows than you need so it may be more efficient.